# Creating new state variables outside of constructor

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am trying to make multiple state variable names from data in an array that is already a state variable. The number of variables needed can change from page load to page load so I can't really initialize them right away

I've set up a function below that I believe should do what I intend for it to, but I can't figure out where to place it in the component.

```
makeButtons() {
    this.state.Buttons.forEach((button) => {
        let key = button.fields.Label

        this.setState({ [key]: '' })
    }); 

}
```

I've tried calling it in render(), but that just gives me a infinite loop error, which makes sense. Any ideas?

EDIT: Tried calling in componentDidMount() but that doesn't seem to work either.  Not sure what the issue would be there. Code below

```
base('ButtonInfo').select({view: 'Grid view' }).eachPage(
            (Buttons, fetchNextPage) => {
                this.setState({
                    Buttons
                });
                fetchNextPage();
            }
        );
        this.state.Buttons.forEach((button) => {
            let key = button.fields.Label

            this.setState({ [key]: '' })
       });
```

EDIT: Answer is in the comments below, I needed to add await before the api call and make componentDidMount() async.

Comment: Which is the event that should trigger the creation of new state properties? Is there an API call, a click on a button or any other async event?

Comment: I would like to create these after an API call that gets the array they are made from.  The API call happens in componentDidMount() and works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing it in componentDidMount()? This method is called only once as the after the app is rendered for the first time, and is often used to initialize the app with some data.

Comment: Trying that, but the variables don't seem to be getting created.  I have the code below. Am I formatting something wrong?
`base('ButtonInfo').select({view: 'Grid view' }).eachPage(
   (Buttons, fetchNextPage) => {
    this.setState({
     Buttons
    });
    fetchNextPage();
   }
  );
  this.state.Buttons.forEach((button) => {
   let key = button.fields.Label
   
   this.setState({ [key]: '' })
  }); 
`

Comment: The code seems fine. Are you using await when making the API call?

Comment: No, the API call seems to be working fine since I can view the pulled in data using React Dev Tools. If I put console.log('someString') statements around the new state variable creation block they are both logged but the variables aren't made. It seems to be skipping over that block for some reason, if that makes sense

Comment: Adding await before API call fixed it, thanks for the help